# Creating array with same keys in a while loop from mysql database - how are duplicate keys handled?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a while loop that adds a key and a variable to an array like this:

```
$array = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
   $array[$row['user']] = $row['variable'];
 }
}
```

and the table it is fetching the data from is over 1000 rows, with duplicate rows for `user` which may have a more updated `variable` value.

What I am wondering is, how does the array handle duplicate keys? Does it;

1) replace  `$row['variable']` with the new one if it comes across

OR

2) skip entering in array since the key; `$row['user']` , already exists

The answer to this will inform how I set up my mysqli_query with either `ORDER BY date ASC` or `ORDER BY date DESC` since I want to ensure the most recent variable inserted is linked to the user.

Comment: Uh, you could write a simple test script to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how the PHP behaves with While loop then sure, it will always replace the last occurrence with the same "key" found. So 1st option.

But you can test that out yourself on any php sandbox available with any simple array replacing.